# Knockout foreach change last item checked element

Tags: knockout.js

Hi how can I set last item of checkbox element in foreach loop to be checked?

```
<ul id="myTaskBox" data-bind="foreach: tasks, visible: tasks().length > 0">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Completed" />
                <input data-bind="value: Title, disable: Completed" />
                <div data-bind="if: ($index() === ($parent.tasks().length - 1))">I'm the last element</div>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeTask">Delete</a>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

I could found they way how get last item, but don't know how change this last item.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it would be to set the last checkbox item as `Completed(true)` in your viewmodel.

Comment: Hi can you please advise how I can use it?

<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Completed, if: ($index() === ($parent.tasks().length - 1)) Completed(true)" /> gives me error...

Comment: Don't do it in the HTML, do it in the Javascript! When you populate the "tasks" observableArray, set it's last element to "Completed(true)".